# How to return the most recent LogTime for each SKU

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

This is what my current query is producing:

```
EventID Sku         User1           LogTime
3510    02821-99-0  Item Inducted   2019-07-08
3510    02821-99-0  Item Inducted   2019-07-06
3510    12573-88-L  Item Inducted   2019-07-08
3510    12573-88-L  Item Inducted   2019-07-07
3510    12948-96-M  Item Inducted   2019-07-06
3510    12948-96-M  Item Inducted   2019-07-05
3510    12948-96-M  Item Inducted   2019-07-05
```

What I want: (The lastest event ID 3510 for each SKU)

```
EventID Sku         User1           LogTime
3510    02821-99-0  Item Inducted   2019-07-08
3510    12573-88-L  Item Inducted   2019-07-08
3510    12948-96-M  Item Inducted   2019-07-06
```

I've tried using the MAX FUNCTION but my query failed.

Below is the query I'm currently using:

```
select
tl.EventID,
tl.Sku,
tl.User1,
--MAX(tl.LogTime) as 'LogTime'
tl.LogTime

from dmhost.tblTransactionLog tl

where tl.logTime between '7/5/2019' and '7/9/2019'
and tl.sku not like 'NULL'
and tl.sku <> ''
and tl.sku not like 'Unknown'
and tl.EventID like '3510'

--group by tl.Sku,tl.EventID
order by tl.Sku
```

I commented out what I've tried.
Thanks!

Comment: SQL Server or MySQL? It cannot be both.

Comment: You may already know this, but I want to be sure you are aware that 'NULL' (a specific value consisting of a four letter string) and NULL (no value specified) are very different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work in SQL Server and MySQL. (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kDhqfwDG2bUcqm5GKUbdj3/0)

First get the maximum LogTime for each combination of EventID and Sku and then join from tblTransactionLog to that.

```
SELECT     tl.EventID
         , tl.Sku
         , tl.User1
         , tl.LogTime
FROM       dmhost.tblTransactionLog tl
INNER JOIN (
               SELECT EventID
                    , Sku
                    , MAX(LogTime) AS MaxLogTime
               FROM   dmhost.tblTransactionLog
               WHERE  LogTime BETWEEN '7/5/2019' AND '7/9/2019'
           GROUP BY   EventID, Sku
           ) AS tmax ON tl.EventID = tmax.EventID
                        AND tl.Sku = tmax.Sku
                        AND tl.LogTime = tmax.MaxLogTime
WHERE    tl.LogTime BETWEEN '7/5/2019' AND '7/9/2019'
```

Comment: this didn't run...any other ideas?

Comment: any chance you can give me a quick explanation to what you added to my query? Would like to understand this as I'm learning on my own.

Comment: @LJG1993 You could also get your desired result by uncommenting your two commented lines, getting rid of tl.LogTime from the selected columns, and adding tl.User1 to the Group By clause. This only works because the values for User1 are all the same. The logic behind my method is to get the max value for the unique combination of values of select columns and then join back to your table to get the rest of the values which may be different for that maximum LogTime value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window analytic function `row_number()` with respect to partitioning by `EventID` and `Sku` columns and due to taking the latest `LogTime` by `order by LogTime desc` :

```
select q.EventID, q.Sku, q.User1, q.LogTime
  from
  (
   select tl.EventID, tl.Sku, tl.User1, t1.LogTime
          row_number() over (partition by tl.EventID, t1.Sku order by tl.LogTime desc) as rn
     from dmhost.tblTransactionLog tl    
    where tl.logTime between '2019-07-05' and '2019-07-09'
      and tl.sku not like 'NULL'
      and tl.sku <> ''
      and tl.sku not like 'Unknown'
      and tl.EventID like '3510'
  ) q
where rn = 1
order by q.Sku
```

Comment: This also did not run. Don't I need "tl." before EventID,Sku etc.. in the first line?

I'm using MIcrosoft SQL Server Mgmt Studio 2014

Comment: @LJG1993 You only need the alias if there is a conflict (e.g. multiple columns with the same name).

Comment: @LJG1993 Do you mean `q.EventID, q.Sku, q.User1, q.LogTime` instead of `EventID, Sku, User1, LogTime` ? You don't need, but you can put, important thing to keep an alias for the subquery(it's `q` in this case, already added).

Comment: @LJG1993 I think you don't have results because of wrong date format. Consider using `logTime between '2019-07-05' and '2019-07-09'` instead of `logTime between '7/5/2019' and '7/9/2019'`

Comment: I know the way I format dates is not "proper" but I know for sure it works.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing this query as:

```
select tl.EventID, tl.Sku, tl.User1, tl.LogTime
from (select tl.*,
             row_number() over (partition by tl.EventID, tl.sku order by tl.logTime desc) as seqnum
      from dmhost.tblTransactionLog tl
      where tl.logTime >= '2019-07-05' and
            tl.logtime < '2019-07-09' and
            tl.sku not in ('NULL', '', 'Unknown') and
            tl.EventID like 3510
     ) tl
where seqnum = 1
order by tl.Sku;
```

Notes:

- Use proper date/time formats so they are unambiguous.  I prefer the hyphens (ISO 8601 standard).  SQL Server prefers the values without hyphens.
- Your string of `comparisons on`sku`is simplified using`NOT IN`.
- `EventID` looks like a number, so I assume it is and dropped the quotes for the comparison and changed the `LIKE` to `=`.
- Aaron Bertrand has a good [explanation](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) of why you don't want to use `BETWEEN` with date/time values.

Comment: Yes Gordon as I just mentioned, issue comes from wrong date format I suppose.

Comment: This ran, but I got repeated SKUs in the results.

Comment: @LJG1993 . . . LOL.  If I define `seqnum`, I should use it somewhere.  Fixed.